# Cron jobs don't execute in parallel

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cron

I have 3 python scripts which are scheduled in the same crontab as :

```
# Script 1
0 20 * * 1-5 cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script1.py >> file1.out
# Script 2
0 * * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script2.py >> file2.out
# Script 3
0 4 1-31 * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script3.py >> file3.out
```

It appears that Script 3 does not get executed - as there is no file3.out. I am facing the same issue with crons that are scheduled to run at the same times as :

```
# Script 1
0 * * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script1.py >> file1.out
# Script 2
0 * * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script2.py >> file2.out
# Script 3
0 * * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script3.py >> file3.out
```

And in this case, only 1 and 3 get executed. I thought that there is a limit on how many crons you can run, but that is not the case.

The scripts are deployed on an EC2, in which I have checked CloudWatch and saw no spike in CPU Usage. What I have seen though is a big spike on Network In and Network Packets In - all scripts are fetching data from APIs, thus the spike I suppose.

My question is, what would be the case that only a number of the scripts get executed? I suppose it's either of the two :

- There is a limit in how many cron jobs you can run (2?)
- There is a cap in Network usage for the EC2 I am using

Any ideas will be highly appreciated!

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I've never heard of cron having a limit like this, but it could be an Amazon restrictions.